# Access UNIX server and run a shell script from java application

Tags: java, unix, ssh

I have got one requirement where i have to access a unix server and on that server i have to run a shell script with some parameter from my java application. 
Please suggest some solution with example.

i have tried something but it is not working.

```
SshWrapper ssh = new SshWrapper();
 try {  
        ssh.connect("10.206.19.80", 22);  
        ssh.login("*****","*****");  

        ssh.setPrompt("c898vqz:~");  
        ssh.waitfor("#");
        System.out.println("PWD**********"+ssh.send("pwd"));  

        ssh.disconnect();
        System.out.println(ssh.getClass());
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

getting `null` from `ssh.send("pwd")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing a shell script with an empty argument from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098308/executing-a-shell-script-with-an-empty-argument-from-java)

Comment: Does anybody have any solution for it instead of down voting this question. If you required any other information i am ready provide.

Comment: @AniketThakur: please refer to my updates.

Comment: @sanbhat does not look like a duplicate . The code in link run on the same server where command needs to be run while this question is asking how to connect to a different unix server .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SSH` component [`JCraft`](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for remote connection and shell commands invocations:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*
```

Exerp from my old code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

String command = "/tmp/myscript.sh";
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.connect();

Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
channel.connect();

byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
  while (in.available() > 0) {
      int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
      if (i < 0) {
          break;
      }
      System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if (channel.isClosed()) {
      if (channel.getExitStatus() == 0) {
          System.out.println("Command executed successully.");
      }
      break;
  }
}
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

You can also easily transfer files via `session.openChannel("sftp")`.

*ooph.. in `java` it is too wordy, than e.g. in `ruby` or `python` :)*

Comment: I an trying to run `FNDLOAD` utility (already installed on server) using this code. But It gives me `command not found` error. Can you help in running `FNDLOAD` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSch js = new JSch();
Session s = js.getSession("username", "ip", port);
s.setPassword("password");
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
s.setConfig(config);
s.connect();
System.out.println("connection ");
Channel c = s.openChannel("sftp");
ChannelSftp ce = (ChannelSftp) c;

ce.connect();
System.out.println("connection ");
ce.disconnect();
s.disconnect();
```

Comment: please, do not just post the code without specify the code i details in able to clarify your code.